# How to access facebook session id in an fbml application?

Tags: session-variables, fbml

I am working on an fbml application which can be added to a fan page. The application then sends ajax request to my php script for data etc.
I have to store some data on my php side against a key or something which remains the same throughout facebook session. How can I implement this? Is there any way to send facebook session id in ajax request? I am using fbml Ajax() element to send ajax request.
Here's a glimpse of code

```
function do_ajax(path)
{   
    var sessionKey = '###'; //Something representing fbml app's session state
    var ajax = new Ajax();
    ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;
    ajax.ondone = function(data) {      
        document.getElementById('content').setInnerFBML(data);
    }  
    ajax.post(path+'/'+sessionKey);
}
```

The visitor may or may not be logged in so I can't use userid. And php session id keeps changing in each request.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FBML is being deprecated.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/  No more support for it in 10 days, and then in 6 months it will no longer work.  I would suggest using the new Javascript SDK.

Comment: I already know that but I am editing an existing application. The requirements are such that I can not create a new app. Till it's deprecation, is there a way around to do the task?

Comment: Where is the fbml hosted?  Your servers, third party servers, facebook servers?

Comment: My server, I mean my client's server but I am developing the back-end. Well thanks for the link, I am shifting the app to iframe :)